# How to add multidomain support in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, frameworks, url-rewriting

I need **city1.example.com**, **city2.example.com**, **city3.example.com** support in CodeIgniter.

Unfortunately, `$config['base_url']` in *config.php* sets the base URL strictly.

What is the best way to learn the framework to support different subdomains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably just search Codeigniter.com next time, as it's all there in the wiki:

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Automatic-base-url

Comment: I thought that so rough changing the config.php might be not the best decision. But if the the official Wiki says that, all is ok then. Thank you!

Comment: The config is there for you to edit, how else would you change some of the settings for your application?  Are you staying clear of editing your other config files too 'database' etc?

Comment: Remember the 'Official' wiki is community driven, not strictly moderated.

Comment: Yeah, it appears that I've become too bureaucratized in my development. :)